# Python terminal printing an empty line during long repeats

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've written a program calculating pi based on basel problem but this program includes a very big while repeat.

See:

```
import math
import decimal

sqrt=1.
sumn=0.
outerrepeat=1000000
while outerrepat>0:
    repeat=10000
    while repeat>0:
        sumn+=1/(sqrt**2)
        sqrt+=1
        repeat-=1
    outerrepeat-=1


print math.sqrt(sumn*6)
```

When I run this outputs an empty line like this without ">>>":

========================== RESTART: C:/Python/pi.py ==========================

What's the reason?

Edit: Sorry for different variables, I wrote this program in my own language and then translated the variables for you. I forgot some of them.
Second edit: I tried Luc's suggestion, also changed the place of the print math.sqrt(sumn*6) to the outer while so I could see if it was proccesing.
It did but after the 7th number of pi it stopped working and stuck at 3.14159264498

Comment: How are you running this, from IDLE or the command-line?

Comment: Please check the definition of `outerrepat`, `tekrar` and `karekok` in your code.

Comment: This code is just a slew of `NameError`s, which nobody can debug by running or stepping through it in their heads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer to your question, is that your `while` loop are too big. So when you execute your program, the time to go through the while loop is too long.

There are some typo in the code that you copy/pasted, but I will assume that there is none. You are trying to make 10 000 000 000 iterations. Do you really need that many?

I would start by simply going for 100 iterations, maximum. And then augment it if you have a need for more precision.

You algorithm would be easier to understand/debug, if you simply use a for-loop.

You can try this one for example:

```
import math

max_iteration = 100
sumn=0.
for n in range(1,max_iteration+1):
    sumn+=1./(n**2)

print math.sqrt(sumn*6)
```

With max_iteration = 100 you should find 3.13207653181, and the precision is getting better if you increase your max_iteration. With 10 000 iterations your are already at 3.14149716395.

Comment: Yeah I got the answer thanks. So it was doing something but the procces was too long.